# Shortcut to Change to a Specific Font

Tags: macos, mac, font

Is there a way to change to a particular font style using a single function key? For instance, I would want to be able to change any font to "Helvetica Bold 16" every time I press F5 if rich text is selected, regardless of application.

Answer (score 2):

You should try and follow the instructions in this answer, [How to create Automator Service to change font of selected text?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83704/how-to-create-automator-service-to-change-font-of-selected-text), I checked it and it works. Follow the assign a shortcut to a script link, https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943, then change Menlo to Helvetica Bold and 18 to 16 in the script provided there. Hope this helped. You can comment here if you run into issues and maybe I can help.